# Is an SQL query using OR equivalent in running time to multiple SQL queries using UNION?

Tags: sql, complexity-theory

It is obviously true that in mathematics, the logical AND and OR are analogous to the set-theoretic INTERSECT and UNION. That is, if A and B are sets, then {x: x IN A OR x IN B} = A UNION B (similarly with AND and INTERSECT).

My question is as follows: does this mathematical equality correspond to running-time equivalency in SQL? Does a single SQL query with a set of OR expressions take time equivalent to a set of SQL queries unioned with each other? More precisely, is this:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.x = a OR A.x = b OR ... OR A.x = z
```

equivalent in running time to this?

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.x = a
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.x = z
```

If the implementation matters, I'm concerned with MySQL (it's what I use at work) and PostgreSQL (it's what I use personally and at university).

Comment: Depends on how the DB's query engine is implemented. I'd guess that the union version is far less efficient in general, but that's just a guess. The union would run `n` sub-queries, then combine their results into the parent query. That'd imply it has to parse those `n` separate queries, execute them, blah blah blah. The `or` version would be a single query, and have just a single pass through the parser.

Comment: It also depends on the distribution of data, and your indexes, sometimes the optimal plan for all conditions is not the same as executing the conditions separately. I would suggest in each case checking the execution plans, and testing on your own data, but bear in mind the answer can vary.

Comment: I know you have cited Postgresql and MySQL, but [here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac883/1) of a data set up and a query where union is faster because OR has to use a merge join to take advantage of the indexes. In [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10991/4) the `OR` version decides that a table scan is more effiecient than a merge join, whereas the union version can still use the two indexes. Basically if any of the predicates in the or could use different indexes it is likely union would be better, if they would use the same index then or would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I expect UNION to be slower in theory. Consider a dataset like so:

```
Firstname  Age
---------  ----
John       20
Matt       30
Jess       30
Nate       20 
Tor        10
Matt       20  // different Matt
```

The query `select Firstname from table where age in (10,20,30)` can go row by row and pluck the data that matches the search criteria.

The query `select Firstname .. UNION .. select Firstname .. UNION ..` would have to go from top to bottom (assuming table scan is happening) 3 times - once for 10, 20 and 30. After getting the data, `UNION` will remove duplicate information. In the test case above, Matt appears twice. They are different Matts but `UNION` will merge the duplicate Matts and report just one (assuming `select firstname from table ...` is done).

As commentators mentioned, database may implement or attempt to rewrite the query differently for optimal performance.